# How to use an integer array for a generic method?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

My insertion sort method is declared using this statement:

```
    public static <AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>> 
          void insertionSort(AnyType[] a){
```

I am having trouble understanding how to make this generic array type parameter accept an array of primitive type `int`.

How would I call this method with `int[]` as my parameter, or at least how would it be used to sort an `int` array?

Comment: I don't believe you can, you'd have to use `Integer` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use a wrapper class - Integer.  There is something called autoboxing which means that if you pass an argument of primitive type int it will convert automatically to Integer :-)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html