# Generic method throws compiler error for numeric array

Tags: java, generics

I'm attempting to call a method that returns the identity of a generic array, supplying arrays of `int`s and `double`s as test data. My typed parameters should implement the `Comparable` interface, but the compiler seems to complain:

```
method identity in class com.me.Test cannot be applied to given types;
  required: T[]
  found:    int[]
  reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: int
    lower bounds: java.lang.Comparable<T>
```

I'm new to Java, so I'm probably missing something. Any thoughts?

Code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = {1};
        double[] arr2 = {1.0};
        System.out.println(Test.identity(arr1));
        System.out.println(Test.identity(arr2));
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] identity(T[] x) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Generics don't work with primitive element types. You would have to use `Integer[]` and `Double[]`, respectively.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use an integer array for a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30008538/12299000)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following (but without primitive element types, as generics do not work with them):

```
public class Main {

    public static <T> Class<?> identity(T[] array) {
    return array.getClass().getComponentType();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr1 = new Integer[]{1};
        Double[] arr2 = new Double[] {1.0};
        System.out.println(identity(arr1));
        System.out.println(identity(arr2));
    }
}
```